# How to sign a string with .p12?

Tags: java, android, signing

I am implementing an SDK and I cant understand the following:

> A copy of the ID that is digitally signed with your private key.

I have the .p12 file and the ID(String) that needs to be signed.

Can anyone help me how would i achieve this in Android/Java?

I've never worked with Encryption and Decryption, So I am little clueless.

Please let me know, If I'm missing something.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [**good example**](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-digital-signatures-example/) of signing a message, with private key. You'll need to know the signature Algorithms (see list of available algo's [here](http://%20https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Signature.)